# Using msal.js the users of Safari (Desktop/iOS) are required to log in twice

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using azure b2c and msal.js on my web app to handle auth on my web app.

When a user clicks login I am calling the login api in the msal.js lib with the needed scopes.

```
function login() {
    clientApplication.loginRedirect(applicationConfig.b2cScopes);
}
```

This works as expected. However when the user attempts to make an API my code calls the acquire token silent api of msal.js which fails every single time in Safari. I believe this is due to an iFrame security policy in Safari. When I turn off "prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari everything works fine.

```
function callApiWithToken(url, type, body) {
    return clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
        return callApiWithAccessToken(url, type, accessToken, body);
    }, function (error) {
        clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
            return callApiWithAccessToken(url, type, accessToken, body);
        }, function (error) {
            throw "Error acquiring the access token to call the Web api:" + error;
        });
    })
}
```

The code above attempts to acquire a token silently fails, then calls the acquireTokenPopup which works but redirects the user to login again first.

Is there a way around requiring the user to login twice? From what I understand the login call only returns an ID token, which is not appropriate for making api calls since I should be using an access token.

Here is the web app if it helps: [link](https://elmbeta.azurewebsites.net/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [solution](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/498) documented by the security team and some other users facing the same issue.

Set navigateToLoginRequestUrl to false in the options object when constructing the UserAgentApplication instance:

```
msalClientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(clientID, authority, () => {}, {
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
})
```